# On travis-ci, how do I encrypt my slack info while also setting on_start, etc

Tags: travis-ci

When I lint my .travis.yml, I am told `in notifications.slack section: unexpected key secure, dropping`. If I remove the

```
on_start: never
on_failure: always
on_success: change
```

section, then it passes the lint.  How do I maintain these settings while still encrypting everything else?

https://lint.travis-ci.org/aaronjorbin/develop.wordpress

Comment: I just tried moving the sucre token under rooms.  It passes lint now, waiting to see if it will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can have the on_start, etc parts as long as you put secure under rooms ALA

```
notifications:
  slack:
    rooms:
      secure: WuMCpfgrm0GIdPbYzsGOsakZ5x7QIbEBwD+CPHVXGKbL3ZbqQ+BVcDRnMiwzxjgf1vzg2de0taXCSMGKBxsWce23NZkOnmwPdIB8XOnwDV7T7zylgYD5S7p3gI6gV0l8Y3/gROdXFZap6viC1qRr4E79ow53RKk7E3WyOo7TWqo=
    on_start: never
    on_failure: always
    on_success: change
```

Comment: Seems like there is still a bug preventing this from working for me - https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/2894#issuecomment-161445087.  Is this still currently working for you?